# How to groupby two columns and calculate the summation of rows using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame `df` like:

```
Name  Hour Activity
    A   4   TT
    A   3   TT
    A   5   UU
    B   1   TT
    C   1   TT
    D   1   TT
    D   2   TT
    D   3   UU
    D   4   UU
```

The next step is to get the summation if the rows have identical value of the column `Name` and `Activity`.

For example, for the case `Name: A` and `Activity: TT` will give the summation of `7`

The result is the presented as below

```
    TT  UU
A   7   5
B   1   0
C   1   0
D   3   7
```

Is it possible to do something like this using pandas groupby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `groupby.sum` and `unstack`

```
df_final = df.groupby(['Name', 'Activity']).Hour.sum().unstack(fill_value=0)

Out[177]:
Activity  TT  UU
Name
A          7   5
B          1   0
C          1   0
D          3   7
```

Answer (score 1):

A `pivot_table` would also work here:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Name', columns='Activity', values='Hour', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
df
Out[1]: 
Activity  TT  UU
Name            
A          7   5
B          1   0
C          1   0
D          3   7
```

From there, you could do some further clean up to get to:

```
df.columns = [''.join(col) for col in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
df
Out[2]: 
  Name  TT  UU
0    A   7   5
1    B   1   0
2    C   1   0
3    D   3   7
```