# How to sum based on the condition of two columns and presented in crosstab format using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

Given the dataframe below:

```
Name    Activity    Hour    Month
A       TT          5       1
A       TT          2       1
A       UU          1       1
A       UU          1       2
A       UU          1       3
B       TT          40      3
C       UU          10      1
D       TT          2       2
D       TT          2       2
D       TT          2       2
D       TT          5       1
```

The next step is to get the summation if the rows have identical value of the column `Name` and `Activity`.

For example, for the case `Name: A` and `Activity: TT` will give the summation of `7`

Then, I would like to present it in a cross tab format which is group according to `month` and `activity`, as shown below

```
                Month
       1           2          3
    TT  UU      TT  UU      TT  UU
A   7   1       0   1       0   1
B   0   0       0   0       40  0
C   0   10      0   0       0   0
D   5   0       6   0       0   0
```

May I know whether this can achieve directly using pandas crosstab?

p.s., similar but different topic has been discussed separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64273360/6446053). Please let me know if this thread is considered to be a duplicate of the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering below df:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]: 
   Name Activity  Hour  Month
0     A       TT     5      1
1     A       TT     2      1
2     A       UU     1      1
3     A       UU     1      2
4     A       UU     1      3
5     B       TT    40      3
6     C       UU    10      1
7     D       TT     2      2
8     D       TT     2      2
9     D       TT     2      2
10    D       TT     5      1
```

**Solution:1** If you want using [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html), you can do this:

```
In [92]: pd.crosstab(df.Name, columns=[df.Month, df.Activity], values=df.Hour, aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
Out[92]: 
Month       1          2          3     
Activity   TT    UU   TT   UU    TT   UU
Name                                    
A         7.0   1.0  0.0  1.0   0.0  1.0
B         0.0   0.0  0.0  0.0  40.0  0.0
C         0.0  10.0  0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
D         5.0   0.0  6.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
```

**Solution:2**
You can use [`df.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [89]: df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns=['Month', 'Activity'], values='Hour', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
Out[89]: 
Month     1      2      3   
Activity TT  UU TT UU  TT UU
Name                        
A         7   1  0  1   0  1
B         0   0  0  0  40  0
C         0  10  0  0   0  0
D         5   0  6  0   0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew that pivot_table and crosstab can be used to give the same presentation.Good exposure

Comment: Yes they are quite similar. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use `groupby` as your previous question

```
df_final = df.groupby(['Month','Activity','Name']).Hour.sum().unstack([0,1], fill_value=0)

Out[338]:
Month     1      2      3
Activity TT  UU TT UU  TT UU
Name
A         7   1  0  1   0  1
B         0   0  0  0  40  0
C         0  10  0  0   0  0
D         5   0  6  0   0  0
```